# Handling GearVR Touchpad input?

Tags: unity-game-engine, touch-event, oculus, unreal-engine4

When I add an OVRPlayerController into a Unity3d scene and build and run the scene for the GearVR the built-in touchpad spins the camera around the vertical axis, which is redundant with head tracking. What do I need to change so that the touchpad instead allows the camera to move forward and backward, as if walking? Is there a thorough tutorial?

Answer (score 4):

The Oculus SDK 0.4.3 comes with the support for the GearVR Samsung GamePad.
All you need to do:

1. import the SDK.
2. overwrite the projectsettings folder of your project with the one that comes with the SDK.
3. add the overplayercontroller to your scene.
4. add a gameobject below the overplayercontroller e.g. plane, quad... this will act like the ground (keep the player from falling)
5. add a collider to the gameobject e.g. mesh collider

then once you run it you will see that you can move around using the gamepad as well as turning the came around the vertical axis...

basically use any first person shooter tutorial for Unity3D and because the Oculus SDK comes with support for the gamepad you can quickly do this...
this link might help
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbm9lPB5GPw

Comment: I will update my SDK and give this a shot. Thank you.

Comment: @MichaelHogan remember to upvote helpful answers and accept the one that solved your problem

Comment: @K.L. Apologize for the super late reply, but this answer doesn't address my question. I asked about the touchpad that is built directly into the GearVR, not the gamepad, which is a separate controller peripheral. This is still an open question likely to help others, though I am not actively pursuing VR development at this time.